# Golang switch statement

Tags: go, switch-statement

I am new to golang and switched from python to golang. How can I convert this if else statement in a "switch"

```
type Client struct {
    Type  string `json:"type"`
}
```

Then I am initializing this struct like this:

```
a:= Client{"v1"}

if a.Type == "v1" {
    if err := apiClient.v1("I am version one"); err != nil {
        log.Printf(" Error: Sending type v1")
        return err
    }
} else if a.Type == "v2" {
    if err := apiClient.v2("I am version 2"); err != nil {
        log.Printf(" Error: Sending type v2\n")
        return err
    }
}  else {
        return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf(" Error: Invalid mertype...This Type"))
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a difficult problem and I'm betting that by taking a quick stab at it you can find the answer.

Comment: The [Spec: Switch statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements) has examples like this.

Comment: It's also [in the tour](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/9).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even though you could figure it out yourself by reading the [doc](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements) here is what you should write:

```
switch a.Type {
case "v1":
    // ...
    // no need to 'break' in go
case "v2":
    // ...
default:
    // usual 'else' clause statements
}
```

Comment: I'm torn between the blatant non-attempt at them trying to figure it out for themselves vs the Stack Exchange sometimes-mantra of "bring it to SO so you don't have to go through the doc"

Answer (score 0):

This is same like any other programming language, just syntax is little bit changed.

you can use switch case as follow :

```
switch a.Type {
case "v1":
    if err := apiClient.v1("I am version one"); err != nil {
        log.Printf(" Error: Sending type v1")
        return err
    }
case "v2":
    if err := apiClient.v1("I am version 2"); err != nil {
        log.Printf(" Error: Sending type v2")
        return err
    }
default:
    return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf(" Error: Invalid mertype...This Type"))
}
```

Even you can combine multiple cases into one too.
like :

```
switch a.Type {
case "v1":
    if err := apiClient.v1("I am version one"); err != nil {
        log.Printf(" Error: Sending type v1")
        return err
    }
case "v2":
    if err := apiClient.v1("I am version 2"); err != nil {
        log.Printf(" Error: Sending type v2")
        return err
    }
case "v3", "v4":
    if err := apiClient.v1("I am version 3 or 4"); err != nil {
        log.Printf(" Error: Sending type v3 or v4")
        return err
    }
default:
    return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf(" Error: Invalid mertype...This Type"))
}
```

Comment: stumbled upon this, looking for something else. I like this answer, except that it's really not the same as any other language. The cases in golang can be full fledge expressions, it's not just integers that you can switch on, and there is no fallthrough between `case`s.